# How to live preview a PDF file which is saved as Longblob data in MySQL Server using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, pdf-viewer

How to make live preview a PDF file in my local website ( no internet ) which is the PDF saved in Longblob? I use this script to download the PDF :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
include "../conn.php";
$query = "select * from file where id = '".$_GET['id']."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error);
$download = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$name = str_replace('%20', ' ',$download['file_name']);
$type = $download['file_type'];
$size = $download['file_size'];
$content = $download['file'];

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$name."\"");
header("Content-length: ".$size."");
header("Content-type: $type");
echo $content;
exit;
}
?>
```

I have use almost all open source PDF Viewer plugins like from http://viewerjs.org , but failed to display the wanted PDF file. Need your help guys..

Comment: Use a PDF generator (which of course, you'll be creating the code). I find this one great of use: http://fpdf.org/

Answer (score 0):

you shoud have a pdf plugin and you should use code looks like :

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-Disposition: inline;filename='document.pdf'");
header("Content-length: ".strlen($binary_contents_from_database));
```